# nginx rewrite based on args

Tags: nginx, rewrite

got links on old site like

```
/aaaa/bbbb/cccc.php?SECTION_ID=112233
```

So i need redirects based on value of SECTION_ID
for example `/aaaa/bbbb/cccc.php?SECTION_ID=112233` leads to `/aaaa/cccc/`,

but `/aaaa/bbbb/cccc.php?SECTION_ID=112244` leads to `/aaaa/dddd/`

I've ended up with

```
location /aaaa/bbbb/cccc.php {
    if ( $args ^SECTION_ID=(112233) ) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /aaaa/cccc/?   permanent;
    }
}
```

But no luck, thanks in advance :)

Comment: How section number and redirect url are connected?

Comment: New enginge on site, so links are a bit different
/aaaa/bbbb/cccc.php?SECTION_ID=112233 - on old site was page with reviews.
on new site page with reviews /aaaa/cccc/

Comment: And where `dddd` came from?

Comment: it's 'hard linked rewrites'

Comment: well. There are `$arg_SECTION_ID` variables. But it's much better to do this kind if stuff in PHP

Comment: I can't do it in php, because site moved from php to java :)

Answer (score 1):

I missed some tildes.  This one works:

```
location ~ ^/aaaa/bbbb/cccc.php {
    if ($args ~ "^SECTION_ID=(112233)") {
            rewrite ^.*$ /aaaa/cccc/? permanent;
    }
    if ($args ~ "^SECTION_ID=(112244)") {
            rewrite ^.*$ /aaaa/dddd/? permanent;
    }
}
```